# I am looking to delete rows in a table based on multiple filter criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using Excel VBA for some time but am now looking to do something with the filters or similar.

I have a large table of data (in excess of 11000 rows) and I need to select up to 5 different criteria in a filter and basically delete each row which does not apply to this filter. (So effectively delete the invisible rows)

The filter needs to be set from an array of information in another listobject

The data in question is a list of staff members in departments set as a listobject - I need to only pull out whichever departments are selected from my criteria on another worksheet.  The depts are Management, Warehouse, Stores, Admin, Transport.  I need to delete all records which are NOT Warehouse, Stores or Admin

*I haven't really tried anything as I have been scouring the internet - I've had some thoughts aroung looping through the filter options

*Sorry - I have tried different things such as the for each row in table loop but this timed at over 15 minutes! (Apologies to the person who commented as I should've advised on this)

Sorry I have no code - barring "for each row in table" loop which I need to avoid using as this is a very slow process with this many records

Had no actual results - been using VBA for years but this is the first time I've been asked for this type of thing and I am at a loss.

Please be kind as I am new to the forum and obviously just looking for some help

Comment: Although I understand your pain, It is not recommended to ask a question without trying anything here. Please checkout the following link:https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1178-excel-delete-visible-rows-only.html and https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3240-excel-filter-and-delete-rest.html

Comment: Sorry - I have edited my original post as I have tried a few things with no acceptable success (for each row in table delete if it's not one of the criteria - took over 15 minutes to run.  Tried the autofilter method but this does not allow more than 2 "<>" criteria!

Answer (score 0):

Having trawled massive amounts of items I am sure there is an easier way but I have resolved this by converting the data back to a range, performaing the loop from the last to first row and deleting the row if the value is not found!

I'm happy with this as it now takes less than 15 seconds to complete - not sure why the list object was slowing it but I'm happy enough with it as is